# How to save database after SQL query ADO.NET?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have the connection to database

```
public SqlConnection CreateConnection()
{
    var con = new SqlConnection(s_connection);
    con.Open();
    return con;
}
```

I have an `INSERT` query after this connection:

```
SqlCommand myCommand = CreateConnection().CreateCommand();
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Departments(Name, Phone) VALUES (@Name, @Phone);";
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
myCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = d.Name;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
myCommand.Parameters["@Phone"].Value = d.Phone;
myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

I want to get a date from database using `SELECT` query, but I don't get any new data that has been added after the query. If I reset the program I see all the data (the `INSERT` query works!) How I can fix this problem?

Comment: After doing the `INSERT` are you doing a `SELECT`? You will have to reload the data to view the newly inserted data.

Comment: Do you have ID column in the Depratments table? Is Date (that you need resides in Departments table?

Comment: If you add the row, alot of times the "presentation layer app" will then have to re-issue a select query......to get the data.  Some call this "re-binding" the data.  Are you wanting to see all EVERY department (in a grid or something) after you do the insert?

Comment: I don't see any `SELECT` command in your question. Where and how are you doing that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ExecuteScalar() function

```
static public int AddProductCategory(string newName, string connString)
{
 Int32 newProdID = 0;
string sql =
    "INSERT INTO Production.ProductCategory (Name) VALUES (@Name); "
    + "SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int)";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.VarChar);
    cmd.Parameters["@name"].Value = newName;
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        newProdID = (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}
return (int)newProdID;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to change your `INSERT` statement. You need to return the **ID** of newly inserted row.

```
Int NewID = 0;
SqlCommand myCommand = CreateConnection().CreateCommand();
myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Departments (Name, Phone) VALUES (@Name, @Phone) SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
myCommand.Parameters["@Name"].Value = d.Name;
myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Phone", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 20);
myCommand.Parameters["@Phone"].Value = d.Phone;

// We will use ExecuteScalar that will return the ID of newly inserted row instead of ExecuteNonQuery
NewID = myCommand.ExecuteScalar();
```

Now you can use the NewId to get your data, General statement would look something like this:

```
Select DateColumn From Deprtments Where IdColumn = NewId
```

Also, notice that in the CommandText we have used `SCOPE_IDENTITY` which returns the **ID** of the row that was just inserted. [Read more about SCOPE_IDENTITY](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/).

I am not sure if you need to retrieve all the details of Departments table, If yes stick to the above solution. If all you care is a Date of newly added record then you can consider returning Date instead of ID. Statement would look something liek this:

```
INSERT INTO Departments (Name, Phone) VALUES (@Name, @Phone) SELECT DateCol From Department Where IdCol = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

Above statement will return you the **Date** using your `Insert` statement only. You don't need to write another `Select` to retrieve the **Date**.